# Relation between wavefunction and actual waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction

I have learned basic QM without the rest of physics such as wave theory, as a course in maths. I want to know if my interpretation is correct:

If our wavefunction is say an eigenfunction of the momentum operator with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then I guess it can model a wave of speed $\lambda$. If measured the position will be random so we have a particle with a definite position instead of a wave and this is what's meant by wave particle duality is this correct ?
If it is correct, to what concept of the wavefunction do frequency and wavelength correspond ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If measured the position will be random

The position will not be random , but biased according to the probability distribution given by the  $Ψ^*Ψ$  of the space solutions  for the boundary conditions of the observation. This is one of the [postulates of quantum mechanics.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) Postulates are extra axiomatic statements imposed in order to pick up from the mathematical solutions those solutions that fit the data and are predictive of new behavior. (They also connect units to the variables). See the wave function postulate in the link.

> to what concept of the wavefunction do frequency and wavelength correspond ?

The  wave nature of the duality is seen in the probability distributions, the interference patterns according to the frequency in the $Ψ$ space solution.

See this [answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/716128/is-wavelenth-of-a-particle-relative-according-to-wave-particle-duality/716134#716134) for wave particle duality that has links for a electron experiment one particle at a time.